# how to count no of records in a temporary table created using WITH clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure using sql server and i need to count no of records in a temporary table created using the 'WITH' clause.
I used that temp table one time as an inner join. Apart from that, I want to count no of records in that record temp table and set that value to `@SlotCount` variable.

I tried it like this(temp table name is cte):

```
SELECT @SlotCount = COUNT(*) FROM cte
```

This gives errors because I used temp table twice in a stored procedure. So please help me to solve this. Thank you

Stored Procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Starttime DATETIME, 
    @Endtime DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @SlotCount int
    
    ;WITH cte AS ( SELECT @Starttime starttime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Starttime) endtime
              UNION ALL
              SELECT endtime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, endtime)
              FROM cte
              WHERE endtime < @Endtime)

              --do something for count no of records in cte table and set that value to @SlotCount
            
            select count(a.AVAIL_ID),a.TEACHER_USERNAME 
            from cte c
            INNER JOIN AvailabilityDetail ad ON c.starttime = ad.StartDateTime AND c. endtime = ad.EndDateTime
            INNER JOIN AVAILABILITY a ON ad.AVAIL_ID = a.AVAIL_ID
            LEFT JOIN TEACHER_BIO b ON a.TEACHER_USERNAME = b.TEACHER_USERNAME
            WHERE ad.IsAvailable = 1
            AND ad.AvailabilityType = 'N'
            AND b.Active = 1
            AND b.IsGroupClass = 1
            AND b.HIDE_FROM_SCHEDULING = 0
            GROUP BY a.AVAIL_ID,a.TEACHER_USERNAME
            

END
```

Comment: *"i need to count no of records in a temporary table created using the 'WITH' clause"* `WITH` doesn't "create" a temporary table. `CREATE TABLE` creates a table. `WITH`, preceeded by a CTE definition, is just an **expression** it doesn't "contain" rows, it doesn't create an object. It's far more similar to a `CASE` expression than a `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: thank you for your explanation. If you can give me a solution to my real problem, it is better. @Larnu

Comment: What is the *real* problem, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store results to temp table and then later return it

```sql
DECLARE @SlotCount int
;WITH cte AS ( SELECT @Starttime starttime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Starttime) endtime
              UNION ALL
              SELECT endtime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, endtime)
              FROM cte
              WHERE endtime < @Endtime)
                          
            select count(a.AVAIL_ID),a.TEACHER_USERNAME 
            INTO #cte from cte c
            INNER JOIN AvailabilityDetail ad ON c.starttime = ad.StartDateTime AND c. endtime = ad.EndDateTime
            INNER JOIN AVAILABILITY a ON ad.AVAIL_ID = a.AVAIL_ID
            LEFT JOIN TEACHER_BIO b ON a.TEACHER_USERNAME = b.TEACHER_USERNAME
            WHERE ad.IsAvailable = 1
            AND ad.AvailabilityType = 'N'
            AND b.Active = 1
            AND b.IsGroupClass = 1
            AND b.HIDE_FROM_SCHEDULING = 0
            GROUP BY a.AVAIL_ID,a.TEACHER_USERNAME

SELECT * FROM #cte

SET @SlotCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #cte)
```